# What is this furniture part, and where can I find one?

Tags: furniture

I am trying to repair some chairs at church. One of them is missing the part in the photo. What is it called, and where can I find one in the US? Metric threads.

Thanks.[image]

Comment: Look on the underside of the chairs. There is probably a manufacturer label with an address/phone number.

Answer (score 3):

That is a barrel nut and bolt. You can find them at most hardware stores, but they are a specialty item, so they may not have the exact ones you need.

You need to take those with you to a hardware store or get the model information of the furniture to identify the size, or calipers to get accurate measurements. I recommend starting by trying to find the make and model of the furniture to contact their customer service.

Answer (score 0):

You can try a company called Tacoma Screw. In my experiences, I've found that metric tends to be a little harder to find for these styles of bolts. You can of course check Amazon, Ebay and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. There are no labels on the chair anywhere. Unfortunately, my parts are unlike any I've been able to find. It is different than a standard barrel nut & bolt, in that there is a threaded hole in the end. The hole in the side is an un-threaded clearance hole for the stud at the bottom. The stud goes into the clearance hole, then the pointed screw goes into the end of the barrel and pins or retains the stud by the hole in the stud.

I am going to see if I can find out from our financial officer who we bought the chairs from. If not, I think I can make the chair work without it.

Thanks,
Ken

Comment: This really should have been an update to your question. :)